# Isomorphism between the dihedral group D2 and the integer group {-1,1}X{-1,1}

Tags: determinant, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

I put all of the elements of $D_2$ into matrix form, giving $[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0\\
0 & 1\end{matrix}]$ ,  $[\begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix}] $ , $[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix}]$, and $[\begin{matrix} -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}]$

Now I have to create an isomorphism between this and the set {(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1,-1)}

I was thinking f(x,y) = (Det(x), Det(y)) where $x,y \epsilon D_2$ but I don't know if I am allowed to use x,y at the same time.

I still have a very loose understanding of isomorphisms so any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An isomorphism shoud map one element to another one, not two elements to one, so in this case we'd need a function that maps a diagonal matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix} \in D_2$$ to an element $(x,y)$ of the set $S = \{ (1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1,-1)\}$ or vice versa. The "cannonical" way to do that is by defining

$$f\left( \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix} \right) := (a,b).$$

Now you just need to show that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: That last part is done simply by showing the kernel is just the identity element of $D_2$ and showing by hand that each element doesn't map to a single element more than once, correct?

Comment: @Big_Tubbz Right, but you could also just write down the list of all four maps and call it obvious:)